# C++ iterator for custom template class

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have nested iterator in my custom stack template class.
The problem I get now is that my nested iterator's constructor does not match when I create an iterator for my stack in the main. I wonder what the problem could be.

```
template <class T>
class stack
{
private:
    int top;
    T st[100];

public:
    class my_iterator
    {
    public:
        my_iterator() : list(0), curr(0) {};

    private:

        stack<T> list;
        int curr;
    };

//publics in stack class
public:
    stack();
    void push(T i);
    T pop();
    void print();
    bool is_full();
    my_iterator begin() {};

};
```

and I create the iterator for stack with the following line in main

```
stack<double>::my_iterator it;
```

Comment: I have found the problem now, but couldn

Comment: Why does your iterator create its own stack??? And a lesser point: Why is your stack a fixed size array?

Comment: @Sebastian, I didn't want to hassle with linked list, beside I just wanted to experiment a little therefore i used an array. And ofc it shouldn't create it's own stack. I made mistake there therefore also got an compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot a `*`:

```
class my_iterator
{
public:
    my_iterator() : list(0), curr(0) {};
private:
    stack<T>* pStack; // Pointer to a stack.
    int curr;
};
```

Of course, you need more members (including better constructors) for the class. But this should at least allow you to create default iterators that do not point to any stack in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your default constructor for `stack` class doesn't accept any parameters. But here:

```
my_iterator() : list(0), curr(0) {};
```

you pass 0 to ctor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the expression list(0).

Instead change to

```
my_iterator() : curr(0) {};
```

The list member will be default initialized. If you want any specific construction to be done refer the [list constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/list/)